# Move /input left

Tags: input

I have a `.tex` file with a table included as an input (`\input{file.tex}`) in my document, but I want to move the table to the centre of the page (left). For graphics this can be done with `\hspace`, but how can I do it for an input?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  I currently cannot imagine what you try to convey.

Comment: It is really straightforward, when I manually adjust e.g a figure like a table, I write:

\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{+1.1cm}\includegraphics{Table}
\end{figure}

How do I make a similar adjustment for a \input instead of a figure

Comment: there is not enough information in your question to answer really. `\input` is just like copying the contents to that point so the fact that it is input does not have any bearing on the commands you can use. For example if the file starts `\begin{tabular}` you can use `\hspace*{1cm}\input{...` as that is the same as `\hspace*{1cm}\begin{tabular}` but if the file starts with a blank line then `\hspace` would be in the paragraph before the table so not move it. So it all depends ....

Comment: That doesn't look straightforward at all, at least to me.  I thought I knew what you meant, but now I'm definitely confused.  I agree: a MWE is needed here.  (I once asked a question on this site and I thought that just this once, I was asking something so obvious that I didn't need a MWE.  I managed to confuse people so badly that it took several days before someone understood me well enough to be able to help.)

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,mathtools,float,calc,textcomp,graphicx,scalerel,tikz,chngcntr,booktabs,dcolumn}
\graphicspath{ }

\begin{document}
\input{table.tex}
\end{document}

Comment: It is a STATA estimation table saved as a .tex using booktabs following this example : http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab.html#esttab012

Comment: you could try treating the `\input` file the same way as a table by hiding it in a centering group: `\begingroup \centering <adjustments> \input{file} \endgroup`,  of course, if the table is wider than the text width, it will exceed the right margin.